# reverse buffer order

Tags: buffers, files, command-line-arguments

I open Emacs from the command line to inspect 10+ files, say like this:

```
emacs *.java
```

However, all the files are listed in reverse order. This is getting kind of annoying--I'd like to start with the A files, not the Z files. Is there any way to just reverse all the buffers? Or even better, a command-line option that opens the files in reverse order, so that Emacs has them the right way around? (Without explicitly typing in every file.)

Answer (score 1):

They're "visited" in the order given, and the buffer list you see sorts them (by default) by order of "recency".
But you can sort them some other way, such as alphabetically: move the cursor into the column of buffer names and press `S` to sort them by their name.

I found this solution in the following way:
- `C-h m` showed me the description of `buffer-menu-mode`.
- In that description `C-s sort` told me there's no sorting option specific to that mode, but `C-s parent` showed this mode derives from `tabulated-list-mode`, so I clicked on this name to find the doc of that parent mode.
- `C-s sort C-s` to find that `S` is bound to `tabulated-list-sort` which does the trick.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the OP is looking at the buffer list: my guess is that  he is just seeing the buffer of the last file in the command-line sequence as the current buffer  and he would like to see the buffer of the first file instead; then killing a buffer should reveal the buffer of the next file in the sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; isn't C-s just a search function?

Killing a buffer does indeed reveal the next buffer. It's not that I can't find a given file, it's that they're in a really wonky order. I'd like to alphabetize the buffers, so that when I move between them (say with C-x (arrow)) I get the next file alphabetically.